# Reload Ajax from the js code

Tags: forms, commerce, javascript, ajax

I am having trouble reloading a page through Ajax from custom JS. There is a form which will change with your choices and this changes are made by Ajax.

How I can change the select list "Leistung" from the code so the price would be updated by Ajax?

As you all know I can't simply write $("select").click(); it doesn't work. Also I tried .trigger() and .mousedown(), actually .mousedown() would work if I use it for the submit button but I wanna change select list value and nothing works there.

What I think is I have two options: I could simulate a REAL click on the select list (which I know I can't), and the other way is to somehow tell the Ajax to reload after changing the select list value.

**To be more clear:**
That select list is the target that I wanna change. I mean if I click on the third row of the table, that click function should change the value of the select list and here is the problem! the Ajax won't reload the price!

Comment: From looking at your example site it appears you've already found a solution (at least the price updates on Firefox on Windows 10 just fine).

Comment: @acrosman Actually that select list is the target that I wanna change. I mean if I click on the third row of the table, that click function should change the value of the select list and here is the problem! the Ajax won't reload the price!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you're looking to trigger is the `onchange` event. JQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) does not trigger onchange automatically. You can either call [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) or trigger the change event

`$('selector').trigger("change");`.

See Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I've seen it before and I tried it but in the wrong way. thX a lot